# need explanation of result returned from findString() function

Tags: c

Why does the following findString() function return the indicated values for the given arguments?

findString ("text", "") returns 0.

findString ("", "text") returns -1.

findString ("", "") returns -1.

I've read up on strstr and looked at other questions and just don't get it.

```
// find s1 inside source, return index number if found, -1 if not found    

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int  findString (const char  source[], const char  s[])  
{  
    int  i, j, foundit = false;  

    // try each character in source   

    for ( i = 0;  source[i] != '\0'  &&  !foundit;  ++i ) {  
        foundit = true;  

        // now see if corresponding chars from s match   

        for ( j = 0;  s[j] != '\0' &&  foundit;  ++j )  
            if ( source[j + i] != s[j] || source[j + i] == '\0' )  
              foundit = false;  

        if (foundit)  
           return i;  
    }  

    return -1;  
}  

int main (void)
{
    int index;

    printf ("index = %i\n", findString("text", ""));
    printf ("index = %i\n", findString("", "text"));
    printf ("index = %i\n", findString("", ""));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru with the debugger? What IDE are you using?

Comment: gcc, minGW and notepad

Comment: A casual reading suggests that function can bail out early and then returns -1. The spacial case looking for an empty string also seems logically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first call returns `0` because an empty string can be found in any string at index zero (except there is a bug in your code, see below)
- The second call returns `-1` because a non-empty string cannot be found in an empty string
- The third call returns `-1` because there is a bug in your code: when the outer loop is not entered (i.e. the `source` string is empty), you should add a special case to return `0` when the search string `s` is empty as well.

Comment: @user6923395 The return should be 0, -1, 0.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the index of first occurrence of `s` in `source`. If `s` is not present in `source`, it will return `-1`